# Binary probit with rare events

Tags: logit, probit, rare-events

I am fitting a binary probit model on a data with rare events in the response variable. I have several questions:

1- How small should the portion of 1's in the binary response variable be to enable us to say the events are rare and the maximum likelihood estimation might have biased results?

2- Does rarity of the binary response variable results in biased estimation in probit models (I know they do in logit)?

3- If the rarity is causing bias in ML estimation, is the common approaches for logit (Firth modification in ML) applicable to probit as well? Is the R package *brglm* with *binomial = link(probit)* recommended to use instead of *glm*?

4- If I end up reporting this in a paper, how should I justify the use of this estimator instead of ML?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would simply recommend trying both the ML and the bias-reduced estimator. Then you see whether the differences are relevant or not. And wrt 2 and 3: Yes, the same issues occur and they can be mitigated using the same bias-reduction approach implemented in `brglm`.